# Smoothing Lines in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, line, postgresql, smoothing

I want to smooth Lines in postgis, to be more specific, I want to smooth road data from OpenStreetMap.

Basicly I thought of something like this scenario.
[image: This would be a possible road segment.]

This would be a possible road segment.

[image]

I want to use ST_LineInterpolate_Point() to select the middle Points

[image]

After this, I want to create New Points between the original ones and the darkgreen helpline. (I have no Idea how to achieve this...)

[image]

I read about circularlinestrings. I hope it will be possible to lay one of these over the darkgreen and red points.

[image]

Finaly I want to use ST_LineInterpolate_Point() again on the circularlinestring (if this is possible) and create some new points(yellow ones), to make a new normal LineString.

To sum up, I am new to PostGIS, but since I haven't found anything helpful for LineSmoothing I need a function where I can input a LineString and the number of yellow points per segment. The function should return a new LineString.

First of all: Is this possible to achieve with just pl/pgsql?

Second, since I am new to all of this, can somebody give me some advice where to start?

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56835/how-to-perform-sia-or-bezier-line-smoothing-in-postgis

Comment: Maybe this [answer][1] could help you.


  [1]: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/58088/7011

Comment: would: "st_curvetoline(st_linetocurve(my_line),1000)" also smooth my line? Or is the curve not realy a curve, because its made from a normal linestring?

Comment: @afalciano and juanluisrp, thanks for those answers. They gave me some interesting imput for my task.